# sort array of objects obj.sort() not working after update obj

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web-frontend

I use Vue for frontend framework and Javascript to sort Items but not working well.
My code is :

```js
let app = new Vue({
        el:"#bodyz",
        data:{
            suppliers:[],
            order:"created_at",
            config:{
                headers:{Authorization : "Basic bHllbG1vdEBnbWFpbC5jb206NmVlYTliN2VmMTkxNzlhMDY5NTRlZGQwZjZjMDVjZWI="},
                params:{
                    filter:""
                }
            },
            status:" Seen",
        },
        methods:{
            sort:function (){
                let subp = this.suppliers;
                let orderby = this.order;
                Object(subp).sort(function (a, b){
                    if (a[orderby] < b[orderby]){
                        return 1;
                    }else if(a[orderby] > b[orderby]){
                        return -1;
                    }else{
                        return 0;
                    }
                });
                this.status = Date.now();
            },
            load:function (){
                let nis = this;
                axios.get("http://localhost/pos/public/api/supplier",nis.config)
                    .then(response=>{
                        nis.suppliers = response.data;
                    });
            }
        }
        ,
        mounted() {
            let nis = this;
            axios.get("http://localhost/pos/public/api/supplier",nis.config)
            .then(response=>{
                nis.suppliers = response.data;
            })
                .catch(function (err){
                    alert(err);
                })
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="bodyz" class="fm-smreap pr_10 pl_10">
    <div class="pr_10 pl_10">
        Sort : <input type="text" v-model="order" v-on:change="sort()">
        Filter : <select v-model="config.params.filter" v-on:change="load()">
            <option value="">All</option>
            <option value="due">Due</option>
            <option value="paid">Paid</option>
        </select>
        <div>{{ status }}</div>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="sup in suppliers">{{ sup.name}} -- Due : {{ sup.due }} Total : {{ sup.total }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

In the picture is the result. The sort function is working but after change the filter the suppliers data is updated from backend `this.suppliers=response.data` and the filter is not working after that. How can I fix or other way to sort it?

Comment: Are you saying the filter works just once?

Answer (score 1):

Watch Property( this example will help )

```js
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    watch: {
      item: {
        handler(val, oldVal){
          console.log('Item Changed')
          console.log(val)
        },
        deep: true
      }
    },
    data: {
      item: [{foo: 'foo'}]
    }
})
setTimeout(() => {
  vm.$data.item[0]['foo'] = 'bar';
},1000)

setTimeout(() => {
  Vue.set(vm.$data.item,1,{'bar' : 'bar'});
},2000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{item}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you! Working well! But I still can't sort it.